# Using SystemJS modules within gulpfile

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, gulp, systemjs

I'd like to know if it's possible to use **SystemJS modules** within the **gulp** configuration file `gulpfile.js`. The reason for this is because I'd like to use TypeScript to write the gulpfile, as this will give me IntelliSense.

I've set up a Visual Studio 2015 project that uses TypeScript as a transpiler and SystemJS as a module loader. My TypeScript files are compiled by Visual Studio. For this, I've added a `tsconfig.json` file with the following settings:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system"
  },
  ...
}
```

Now I want to add **Gulp** to the project and write the gulpfile in TypeScript. I created a gulpfile.ts and imported the TypeScript definition file. This is `gulpfile.ts`:

```
import * as gulp from 'gulp';

gulp.task('default', () => {
    console.log('hello from gulp');
});
```

And this is the first line of the compiled `gulpfile.js`:

```
System.register(['gulp'], function(exports_1, context_1) {
```

Naturally, `System` is used because that's the module loader I configured in `tsconfig.json`. When running gulp from the command prompt, I get this error:

> ReferenceError: System is not defined
>       at Object. (gulpfile.js:1:63)

**My question**: is there any way to make gulp accept SystemJS modules, so I can write the gulpfile in TypeScript while keeping System as a module loader (at least for the rest of the project)?